# Data frame calculations after performing kproto

Tags: r, dataframe

After performing k-prototypes over the diamonds data set from ggplot2, I want to calculate the median prices for each of the 4 clusters from the k-proto using the dt[i, j, by] command.

```
# install.packages("clustMixType")
library(clustMixType);

# Check classes
sapply(diamonds, class);

#transform data frame
dat <- as.data.frame(diamonds);

#transform classes besides "numeric" and "factor"
non_numeric <- colnames(dat)[sapply(dat, class) != "numeric"];
dat[, non_numeric] <- data.table(sapply(dat[, non_numeric], as.factor), stringsAsFactors = TRUE);

# Check classes
sapply(dat, class);

# Perform k-prototypes
clustering <- kproto(x = dat, k = 4, verbose = TRUE, lambda = 2);

#checking total distance
clustering$tot.withinss

class(clustering)

# get the median price value for each final cluster obtained using a dt[i, j, by] command

clustering[clustering$cluster,median(clustering$price), keyby = "cluster"]
```

Since "clustering" is not a data frame at this point (and I did not manage to cast it to one) I was wondering how to do it if I want to use the process described (using the dt[i, j, by] command).

Any input?

Answer (score 0):

So, I cant reproduce this large exemple, so i run only 10 columns of diammonds data set, but, maybe this is of some help:

```
df1 <- data.frame(clustering[["centers"]][["price"]])
df2 <- data.frame(clustering[["data"]][["price"]])
df3 <-qpcR:::cbind.na(df1, df2)
```

if( or when) another person come up with a better answer I will remove mine, or if this is of no help.

Also check: package `clprofiles` (dont run on my R version)

Comment: I can't run the package you mention either (R version 3.6.2)